# Is there a way to call a class "New"?

Tags: php

Maybe a stupid question, but anyway...

Is there a way to call a class "New"?

```
Class New
{
    ..
}
```

Won't work of course, is there another way?

Comment: yes, change the name of the class

Comment: Thats a great idea! But wait ... then the classes name isn't "new" anymore, right?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Great. Could the OP explain, _why, for goodness sake, it should be named "new"_?

Comment: I do not think this should be closed. The more general question is: "What is so darn special about PHP parsing that rejects this construct even though the case differs?" And *who* changed the casing?

Comment: @Luis Apparently no longer changes can be seen. If "new" was meant (not "New"), then please revert/fix the post. If the issue also applies with "New" then add that information/example as well! Also, include the PHP version used in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

new is a reserved word in php. a class with name "new" is not valid php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: The name is "New", not "new" -- why does this apply then?

Comment: Because PHP labels (i.e., class names, function names and language constructs) are *not case-sensitive*.  `CLASS FOO` is the same as `class foo` and both can be instantiated with `New Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use (most of) PHPs keywords as identifier of classes, methods or functions. Just avoid them. However, `New` is a really bad classname anyway, because its anything, but not self-speaking.

Answer (score 1):

No, the word "new" is a reserved keyword (in probably all modern languages). You can't name anything "new". See the documentation for more detail: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: But consider that `class New {}` (or the equivalent) is valid in a myriad of other languages (Ruby, Scala, Java, C#, etc), what *specific* thing makes it invalid in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a class `"New"`, but it requires some stupid workarounds to actually use it:

```
class Old { /* ... */ }
class_alias("Old", "New");

$New = "new";
$n = new $New;
```

That's the only way to circumvent the reserved keyword issue. (`New` and `new` are the same in PHP, as it is case-insensitive for bare identifiers.)

Comment: Requires PHP 5.3, is really horrible, and not practically useful... but +1 because I learned something new today.